# Laguerre polynomial and series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials, laguerre

Let $L^\alpha_n(x)$ be Laguerre polynomials of type $n$.
Consider the sum
$$\sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{1}{(b-j)}L^{m}_j(x)$$

where $b\not\in\Bbb N,x>0$ and $m\in \Bbb N$.
I have found this series converges [A. P. Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov, and O. I. Marichev, Integrals and Series, Vol. 2, Special Functions
(Gordon and Breach, New York, 1986), p. 703.]but I don't know how to prove that.

**Here my attempt:**

By  Mehler's formula, for the Laguerre functions. For $|w|<1$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+\delta+1)} L_k^\delta(t) L_k^\delta(s) w^k \\
= & (1-w)^{-1}(-t s w)^{-\frac{\delta}{2}} e^{-\frac{w}{1-w}(s+t)} J_\delta\left(\frac{2(-t s w)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-w}\right) .
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $J_\delta$ is  the Bessel function of order $\delta$.
Multiplying by $w^{\beta},\beta>0$ and integrating with respect to $w$ betwen $0,1$, we obtain

\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+\beta}\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(k+\delta+1)} L_k^\delta(t) L_k^\delta(s)  \\
= &\int^1_0  w^\beta (1-w)^{-1}(-t s w)^{-\frac{\delta}{2}} e^{-\frac{w}{1-w}(s+t)} J_\delta\left(\frac{2(-t s w)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{1-w} \right)dw .
\end{aligned}

Since $L_k^\delta(0)=\frac{\Gamma(k+\delta+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(\delta+1)}$ and

$\lim_{x\to 0} \big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^{-\delta}J_\delta(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\delta+1)}$ the above equation becomes
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+\beta} L_k^\delta(t)  \\
= &\int^1_0 w^\beta (1-w)^{-(1+\delta)} e^{-\frac{w}{1-w}t} dw .
\end{aligned}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When $b=-1$ and $m=0$  your sum is $$-e^x\int_x^\infty \frac{e^{- u}}{u}\,du$$ When  $b=-1/2$ and $m=0$ your sum is $$-e^{x/2}K_0(x/2)$$ You can see these at V. Ditkine and A. Proudnikov, Calcul Operationnel

Comment: You can see also the case $b=0$ and $m=0$, the sum being $\log x+\gamma$.  Starting at $j=1$.

Comment: There are two questions here: (i) about a closed-form formula and (ii) about the convergence. According to MathOverflow guidelines, there should be only one question in one post. Please edit your post accordingly. Anyhow, (i) a general closed-form expression (except for a trivial expression in terms of a hypergeometric function $_pF_q$) seems unlikely and (ii) the series clearly diverges at $x=0$; so, what is your $x$?

Comment: ok@ losif Pinelis

Comment: @juan. I see them . Thank you

Comment: @zoranVicovic : Do you have the formula number in that handbook?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis.See the page 703 in that book

Comment: Another paper where I found my formula  see the paper[Resolvent of harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian and its application to Fourier transform for generalized functions] formula 12.

Comment: @zoranVicovic : Can you provide a reference to Mehler's formula for the Laguerre functions. More importantly, how do you justify the pointwise integration of the series?

Comment: For a reference see page 102 of this book https://people.math.osu.edu/nevai.1/SZEGO/szego=szego1975=ops=OCR.pdf. I can't justify the inversion integeral-series.

Answer (score 3):

The handbook by A. P. Prudnikov, Yu. A. Brychkov, and O. I. Marichev (PBM) seems hard to use, because they do not provide references to specific formulas and sometimes they do not even say for what values of the variables the formulas hold.

In your case, the formula in question is formula 5.11.1(1) on p. 703 of PBM, given there without any specifications on $\alpha$ (equal $m$ in your case) and $b$, and without any specific reference.

This formula is given (for $x>0$) as formula (26) on p. 215 of *Higher transcendental functions 2* by Erdelyi (with $-a\in (-1/2,1)$ in place of your $b$) and the case $-a=-1$ is given there as formula (19) on the same page. References to these formulas are given on p. 217 of that volume. No results seem to be known for other values of $a$.

Comment: Thank you @losif Pinelis. Please see above  for a proof